# Some good reference on convex functions

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

I want some good reference on convex

functions i.e. all of their properties

along with their proofs.

Comment: http://stanford.edu/class/ee364a/

Comment: @Nameless: Boyd's lectures are from optimization/engineering point of view. I want the mathematics part. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function works for me, but has not proofs.

Comment: Rockafellar's Convex Analysis is the oldie but goodie...